# Comparing the i from loop with the passed value

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates

I use a Django 1.2 templates in Google App Engine wepage.

I pass a `agemin`  to template to mark  option as selected  in html form.
But code below dosn't work.

The `age` is created by `range(18,100)`

How to compare 'i' with agemin?

```
    {{agemin}} //this is for example 23
    <select name=agemin><BR>
        {% for i in age%}
            <option {% if i == agemin %}selected{% endif %}>{{ i }}</option>
        {%endfor%}

    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [ifequal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#ifequal) tag:

```
{% ifequal agemin i %}
```

Comment: i tried it, it dosnt work too. It looks strange but both ways don't work.Just guessing but might it be becouse of types of data? (ie int and text?)

Comment: Yes, that matters too. Check if agemin is an integer.

Comment: Thrustmaster: Thank you, agemin was passed as text value and 'i' was integer